Problem in sending bulk email to users in PHP ? I've encountered a challenge with our website's email functionality
I've encountered a challenge with our website's email functionality. Currently, we're using PHP mailer to send notifications about job openings to our users. However, after sending emails to approximately 40-50 users, we encounter timeout errors. Increasing the timeout settings allows for an additional 10-20 emails, but this is not a scalable solution as our user base continues to grow.
To ensure seamless communication with candidates, we need to implement a more robust email delivery system.
What will be the best solution for this problem ?

Are you sending them out all at once or batching them? In any case you should send them in small batches. If I understand correctly you can send 30 emails in batches for an infinite amount or do you need to send them immediately?

It sounds like your mail relay has a rate limit to prevent spamming.

you may need to use a pay service like Twilio SendGrid. Free mail relays are often abused by spammers so they need countermeasures like this.

Andy - I simply send them one by another in a loop. I simply tum loop and send mail to each user. So what can be done now ?

Barmar - I am sending mail through loop in PHP by calling user table and sending mail from php mailer

I agree with Barmar, you need a mailing service. One with a proper API. These services often offer more than just sending emails. For instance they can report on deliverability. You have to look around, because the once that are suggested most, like Sendgrid, aren't the best by a long way.

It seems pretty obvious your mail server is taking action to prevent spammy behaviour, right?  So the options are pretty clear: 1) Try not to be spammy.  Are you pausing inside your loop, or just hammering away 1 after the other?  Have you contacted your mail provider to ask what you could do to not trip their antispam protections?  Though if you need to send large volumes of mail, you really should ... 2) Use a service designed for high mail volumes like Mailgun, Sendgrid, etc.

I need to send personalized emails to users, with each email containing unique content such as the recipient's name. However, when sending emails in a loop, I encounter an issue where the maximum execution time is exceeded. Although increasing the execution time is a temporary solution, I am looking for a more effective method to handle this task. Could you suggest a strategy to send emails with dynamic content efficiently, without running into execution time limits?
The issue isn't with spanning but with sending bulk emails to users.

Is that the php max execution time? In that case, run your mail functionality as a background service instead of directly from a http request. Then you avoid web script timeout limitations. The script which responds to the http request would just note that its time to send emails and collect any needed input data, and store it. It would then notify the background service that a job needs to be processed - e.g. by writing data into a database row, or a message queue. The background service (either a daemon or a regularly scheduled cron job) then picks up the work and takes as long as it needs

P.s. in your question it's unclear precisely what is timing out. Always paste in exact error messages and try to be specific in your description. It could have been php script timeout or it could be rejections by the mailserver as some suggested. These problems have different solutions.  You can [edit] your post. Always remember we can't see your screen.

P.P.s. even if spam isn't the main problem here, you should still consider using a dedicated bulk mail system as people suggested above. If your volumes continue to increase substantially you'll eventually run into just the same problems anyway

@Dipesh, I think we have all been where you are at some point. In PHP it is very easy to send email, or more specifically, call an email sending function. Because the function is simple, calling it in a loop should also be simple, right? Abstractly yes. Unfortunately reality is very different. Email systems, especially as of Feb of 2024, are making it increasingly more complex to get a message to a user's inbox because of spam, phishing, etc. It isn't impossible but you'll need to setup SPF, DKIM and DMARC, and have a clean IP address, which is why many of us recommend using a service instead.
